# In the bibliography, how to show a series of papers in one item?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

What should do if I want to show a series paper in one line like this

[image]

Comment: This looks like any regular bibliography entry. Where is the problem?

Comment: For example, how to input two years (1963) and two different pages (563--626) and (1--40)?